# Convert 2 forloops to linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have function

```
private void TotalOutcome(List<Prenumerator> prenumerators, List<Publication> publications)
    {
        foreach (Publication publication in publications)
        {
            foreach (Prenumerator prenumerator in prenumerators)
            {
                if (prenumerator.PublicationCode == publication.Code)
                {
                    publication.Earnings += prenumerator.Count * publication.MonthPrice;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**How can i convert this to linq?** My current approach doesn't work, doesnt do anything:

```
publications = (from publication in publications
                from prenumerator in prenumerators
                where prenumerator.PublicationCode == publication.Code
                select publication);
                    {
                        publication.Earnings += prenumerator.Count * publication.MonthPrice;

                    }
    );
```

Comment: linq is for querying data, not modifying it

Comment: You could tag on a `ToList().ForEach()` if you select both the `publication` and `prenumerator` in an anonymous class, but personally I'd just leave it as is now.

Comment: So this is impossible?

Comment: @Mažas Not impossible.  You can use Linq to query the `publication` you want to update and the `prenumerator` you want to update them with, but you still have to loop over those results to do the actually mutation.  It's just not really recommended.

Answer (score 2):

As others has mentioned, LINQ isn't the right tool for update operation. You can still do this partially using LINQ i.e for the calculation part, and then use plain `foreach` loop for the update part, for example :

```
foreach (Publication publication in publications)
{
    var total = prenumerators.Where(o => o.PublicationCode == publication.PublicationCode)
                             .Sum(o => o.Count * publication.MonthPrice);
    publication.Earnings += total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the 2nd loop like this

```
  private static void TotalOutcome(List<Prenumerator> prenumerators, List<Publication> publications)
        {
            foreach (Publication publication in publications)
            {
                foreach (Prenumerator prenumerator in prenumerators.Where(prenumerator => prenumerator.PublicationCode == publication.Code))
                {
                    publication.Earnings += prenumerator.Count * publication.MonthPrice;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to be pedantic and go full Linq (I think that's the quote from Forest Gump).  This is an "improvement" on har07's code; however, depending on your coding standards where you work, some places may not like this much gratuitous use of Linq.

```
publications.ForEach(publication =>
    {
        publication.Earnings = prenumerators
                         .Where(o => o.PublicationCode == publication.PublicationCode)
                         .Sum(o => o.Count * publication.MonthPrice);
    });
```

We actually have a rule at our shop that you're not allowed to use .ForEach if the delegate you're going to put inside of it is longer than one line.

Answer (score 0):

Step one, we apply a bit of the law of association:

```
         var cnt = 0;
        foreach (Prenumerator prenumerator in prenumerators)
        {
            if (prenumerator.PublicationCode == publication.Code)
            {
                cnt += prenumerator.Count;
            }
        }
        publication.Earnings = cnt * publication.MonthPrice;
```

This makes the next step easier:

```
publication.Earnings = prenumerators
                        .Where(p=>p.PublicationCode == publication.Code)
                        .Aggregate(p=> p.Count)) * publication.MonthPrice;
```

There's no particularlly good way to get rid of the outer loop.